# Search closed question by specific type

Tags: support, search

We know that we can search for closed questions with

```
closed:1
```

But how do i search closed questions by a specific type?, lets say questions that are closed because it needs more focus or questions that are closed because it is off-topic

Perhaps something like

```
[javascript] closed:1 needfocus:1
```

Is this possible? i tried reading the [how do i search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) but still couldn't find it

Comment: AFAIK there is only a filter for duplicates, nothing else. The close reasons have changed over the years, so maintaining a filter for each type is probably hard.

Comment: Here you go: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1440645